# angular how to resize ngx-datatable while closing and opening nav bar

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-datatable

Before clicking on the on the navbar the `<ngx-datatable>` looks like this

[image: Before clicking on nav bar]

And after  clicking on the navbar it looks like this

[image: Before clicking on nav bar]

As you see in the second picture the navbar columun did not resize after clicking.

Here is the code

```html
<ngx-datatable
  #table
  class="material"
  [rows]="data"
  [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
  columnMode="force"
  [headerHeight]="60"
  [footerHeight]="80"
  rowHeight="auto"
  [limit]="10"
  [scrollbarH]="scrollBarHorizontal"
  [reorderable]="reorderable"
  [selected]="selected"
  [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
  (select)="onSelect($event)"
>
```

I looked for help but but couldn't find the solution. Thank you.

Comment: add ```[]``` on ```columnMode```

Comment: did not compile

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the rows of the table every time you click on the side bar toggle.

In my use case, I needed to do the refresh after some amount of time along with `ChangeDetectorRef` to make it work.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // ...
  }

  
  // Call this function every time you close or open your sidenav
  resizeTable() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.data = [...this.data];
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    }, 500);
  }

}
```

Hopefully this helps!